# wxWidgets oposite of appending to a wxChoice list

Tags: c++, append, codeblocks, wxwidgets

im building a basic GUI for a college project, im using wxwidgets and codeblocks because c++ is my comfort programming languaje. However, I want to modify the options on a wxChoice because those options are not meant to be always the same, that means that if I append something to the choice list and then i want to update the list to a complete different list, first i have to remove the old items from the choice list and then append the new ones, but i cant find how to do that. Here's my code:

```
//Event
void TestFrame::OnChoice1Select(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    fstream in;
    string str,str2;
    int i;

    //File where I store my list of lists
    in.open("Recursos/Carreras-LC.txt",ios::in);

    //Go to an specific line of the file where the list for the current choice is
    in=gotoLine(in,Choice1->GetSelection()+1);

    //Gets the line with the list
    getline(in,str,'\n');
    in.close();

    //Here is where I'll put the code to remove the current list of choices

    //My code to append the items from the list i got before
    i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(str[i]==','){
            Choice2->Append(_(str2));
            i++;
            str2="";
        }else{
            str2+=str[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also if there's a better way to do this kind of dynamic GUI please tell me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have to remove the old items from the choice list and then append the new ones, but i cant find how to do that

You can use the wxChoice::Clear() method to remove all entries from a choice control, and you can use the wxChoice::Delete(unsigned int n) method to remove a specific entry from the control.

They're listed on the [documentation page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_choice.html) under the "Public Member Functions inherited from wxItemContainer" section.

> Also if there's a better way to do this kind of dynamic GUI please tell me. thanks in advance.

One option would be to use the [wxUpdateUIEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_update_u_i_event.html) in order to update the choice when the main frame is idle.  If you're going to go that route, I would

1. add a bool member named `m_choiceNeedsUpdate` or something like and an event handler `void OnUpdateUI(wxUpdateUIEvent& event)` (or what ever you want to call it) to the class of your application's form.
2. Bind the event handler in the frames constructor with a call like `this->Bind(wxEVT_UPDATE_UI,&MyFrame::OnUpdateUI,this);`
3. When you do something that requires the choice to be updated, you can arrange for it to be updated with calls like these:

   ```
   m_choiceNeedsUpdate=true;
   this->UpdateWindowUI();
   ```
4. The body of the event handler where the choice control is updated might look something like this

   ```
   void MyFrame::OnUpdateUI(wxUpdateUIEvent& event)
   {
       if (m_choiceNeedsUpdate)
       {
           //Update the choice control here (probably using the Clear/Delete methods)
           m_choiceNeedsUpdate=false;
       }
   }
   ```

The advantage of going this route is that all of the logic concerning updating the UI can be placed in one method/event handler.  This is especially nice if you have several controls that might need to be dynamically updated.

The downside is that there will be a lot of calls to that event handler when your frame is running which can potentially effect performance.  That's why I guarded the logic for changing the choice control with the m_choiceNeedsUpdate bool variable in the example above.

Comment: `wxEVT_UPDATE_UI` is not meant to be used like this, it is supposed to update the control directly instead of setting a flag. If you do just this, it'd be less confusing to just use `wxEVT_IDLE` directly.